# Which circuit is better for P-Channel MOSFET ESD and over-voltage protection?

Tags: mosfet, esd, over-voltage-protection, p-channel

There was damage to some P-channel MOSFETs on the PCB due to ESD and dielectric strength tests during our manufacturing.

I think the original circuit design is susceptible to high voltage stress.

A TVS is installed from gate to GND like N-channel MOSFET protection (not gate-source) and the drain is floating.

The drain is connected to a touchable connector (not protected.)

The gate is also connected to a connector but it has ESD protection from the TVS diode.

The MOSFET was damaged during ESD with (-)3kV at the floating drain pin.  Other test conditions were OK.

The MOSFET was also damaged during our dielectric strength test(3kV.)

All circuit terminals were open, but voltages were induced due to capacitive coupling(?).

There are 2 choices for protection in our scheme:

- Choice #1 (schematic "Before") - only(?) for ESD protection.

  - TVS across gate-gnd is remained
  - Add TVS across drain to gnd (ESD Failure protection-> ESD was OK).
- Choice #2 (schematic "After") - for ESD & dielectric strength test protection.

  - TVS is relocated at to the gate to source pin.
  - TVS or Schottky diode across drain to gnd is optional.

I think Avalanche breakdown will protect the FET.  For too high energy & dv/dt, I think only theSchottky diode (not TVS) is useful because (+) charge can flow due to MOSFET forward diode at D-S and (-) charge can flow due to Schottky diode during ESD.

In my opinion, to protect ESD and any other high voltage, choice #2 is better and cheaper.

What do you think?

[image: Circuit Before(Choice #1) & After(Choice #2]

Comment: #1 isn't even protecting the gate-source which is the most sensitive junction. No wonder it died. It almost looks like you're just tossing TVS diodes everywhere hoping they will do something. Your PCB also needs proper layout and chassis planes for ESD. It's not just about ESD diodes. Check out Henry Ott's book.

Comment: I agree with you. PCB pattern will be checked again. There's no chassis only plastic. How about #2 circuit concept. Should optional schottky diode be needed? or not?

Comment: If there is no chassis then ESD is very difficult to protect against in any form. If you're serious you should add a large area metal plate inside the enclosure. Thickness does not matter, even foil would do, and sink your ESD at all expected entry points to the plate as far away from the PCB as possible as per Henry Ott. The objective is to increase the free space capacitance and shunt ESD to that plate before it gets close to your board because once it does, it AC couples to everything.

Comment: If it is exposed, shunt it to the plate. Then TVS across gate-source because it is particularly sensitive. You may also shunt both gate and source to the plate, even if the source is not an entry point. ESD can be both common mode or differential...you never know.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation. But, there's no space to insert conductive matrial. It's kind of very small pcb. So we have to improve by revising the circuit. I think #1 is not good deaign. How about #2 circuit to protect ESD and dielectric strength high voltage with capacitive coupling? I think it will be  much better for over voltage stresses.

Comment: Never seen protecting the source itself… it's the reference point for the mosfet! the Vgs zener is the most common since it's *the* weak point for the MOSFET. Vds can be an issue if you are risking avalanche (like for inductive switching)